# Change url to not include /index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple profile system in place that has a URL re-write that changes URLs like:

```
www.domain.com/profile.php?id=user
```

To:

```
www.domain.com/user
```

Using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That being said, how would I change the URL:

```
www.domain.com/something/index.php
```

To:

```
www.domain.com/something
```

Without disrupting the profile URL setup? Would I just put the rewrite higher up in the .htaccess file? Thank you for helping a rookie out.

Comment: try  RewriteRule ^something  something/index.php [L]

Comment: `something` is constant or can be anything?

Comment: well it might be www.domain.com/forums/index.php or www.domain.com/questions/index.php

Comment: @Kragalon it is not possible to do that, you need to use different url pattern for that. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `something` is not constant it is not possible to do that, you need to use another url pattern like `www.domain.com/page/something`. However, if the `` `something `` constant, you can use;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond !^something [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond ^something [NC]
RewriteRule ^something something/index.php [L]
```

If you use different url pattern like ;

`www.domain.com/page/something` you can use;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but I think it is possible to do. As an example, [www.twitch.tv/directory](http://www.twitch.tv/directory) and [www.twitch.tv/lassiz](http://www.twitch.tv/lassiz) reference completely different php scripts, yet they have the same layout.

Comment: However, how did you know it is a directory or username? You need to check it programatically. If you know a way to determine `something` a user or directory I can show you the solution how to solve. As I said you above, if `something` is constant it is possible. Or If you have list for directories that is also possible. You need to give rewrite cond to do that

Comment: So your answer would work if I say, wanted 'something' to be 'forums' as in: www.domain.com/forums/index.php to become www.domain.com/forums  ? Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: My answer works if you say `www.domain.com/page/forums/index.php`, In order to make your condition work, I need a list of directory to act like a directory instead of user profile. Thi links you have gavme me probably use constant url pattern. I mean, site owner implemented a controller with url mapping `/directory`. When user go to this url, custom controller works. But in this url, `http://www.twitch.tv/lassiz` url rewrite works. In this case there is a order. First goes to controller mapping and it goes user profile, if it cannot find any matching.

Comment: It seems I have gotten what I wanted with:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^forums/$ forums/index.php [L]

Am I being foolish?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be blind. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In this case, you have constant url mapping `forums`. This case is stated in my answer

Comment: One more thing actually. When I type in www.domain.com/forums it doesnt work yet when I use www.domain.com/forums/ it does. Is there something wrong with my code or is that something I need to live with?

Comment: Use this `RewriteRule ^forums forums/index.php [L] `

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove `/index.php` from any where:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```